# How to upload a file starting at a byte position with React-Native Expo?

Tags: file, react-native, upload, google-cloud-storage, expo

I am trying to set up resumable upload to Google Cloud Storage on a React Native Expo App. If the connection during an upload is broken, I need to be able to continue the upload from a byte position.

However, I cannot find a way to slice a binary file at a byte position so that I can resume the upload using Expo's FileSystem API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by converting the file to a Blob and using blob.slice to resume the upload.

Comment: Can you share the method

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you’re looking for. [Using the JSON API you can do resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#upload-resumable) to Cloud Storage, you can set the byte size in the `Content-Length` header.

You can also do [parallel upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#_Uploads) with Cloud Storage

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I am indeed using GCS resumable upload API successfully on browser. This question pertains specifically to how to get it to work in React Native Expo.

Comment: What have you try so far? are you getting errors from GCS API? connection issue? Do you have have error logs you can post?